# Baby Rudin 3.7 Theorem - my alternative proof (why Rudin chooses to divide distances by 2?)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to present my alternative proof to theorem 3.7 from Baby Rudin.

Either it is correct and thus Rudins proof is just a bit more complicated but equal in power, or my proof is wrong and I am missing some detail from Rudins proof.

So theorem states:

> The subsequential limits of a sequence $ \{p_n\} $ in a metric space $ X $ form a closed subset of $ X $

My strategy is exactly the same as Rudins:

Take limit point $ q $ of $ E^* $, where $ E^* $ is a set of said subsequential limits, and show that $ q $ is a limit of some subsequence of $ \{p_n\} $. The difference will be in how the subsequence is constructed.

Since $ q $ is a limit point, there exists $ x \in E^* $ such that $ d(q, x) < 1 $, where $ 1 $ was chosen arbitrarily.

But then $ 0 < 1 - d(q, x) $, so, since $ x $ is a limit of some subsequence of $ \{p_n\} $, there exists $ n_1 $ such that $$ d(x, p_{n_1}) < 1 - d(q, x) $$ so: $$ d(q, p_{n_1}) \leq d(q, x) + (x,p_{n_1}) < 1 $$

Now assume we have already chosen $ p_1, ..., p_{n_{k-1}} $.

We find $ x \in E^* $ such that $ d(q, x) < \frac{1}{k} $.

We can find $ n_k $ such that $$ d(x, p_{n_k}) < \frac{1}{k} - d(q, x) $$

so, as previously, we get:

$$ d(q, p_{n_k}) < \frac{1}{k} $$

Since there is infinitely many such $ p_k $ (there is infinitely many of them around limit $ x $), we can get $ n_{k-1} < n_k $.

We thus obtain subsequence $ p_{n_1}, p_{n_2}, ... $, which obviously converges to $ q $, since we can make $ \frac{1}{k} $ as small as we want.

## My questions

Is the basic idea of proof correct?

Are there any important details I have missed, which I should clarify?

Is there a reason why Rudin decides to divide distance by two between every iteration of choosing next $ p_{n_k} $, or is it simply another way to get a sequence that tends to $ 0 $ as $ n $ get larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your basic idea is correct.

No, there are not important details that you have missed or should clarify.

Not really. As you have probably understood, one may choose any sequence $a_k$ tending to zero. You chose $1/k$; Rudin chose $2^{-k}$. Between these two choices, there is no special advantage in choosing one or the other. The choice $2^{-k}$ is a kind of universal choice because it can also be summed up and converge, if necessary. In this proof it is not necessary, but somewhat customary.